# Spring @Cacheable not working properly with custom key in spring

Tags: java, spring-boot, caching, ehcache, spring-cache

For different values of cachedData it's fetching response Date every time from cachedData in parameter while as per my understanding if for a particular propertyId if there has been some call with some cachedData param it shouldn't fetch again instead it should pick from the cache.

MyMethod

```
@Cacheable(value = "responseCached", key="#propertyId", condition = "#result != null")
public Date fetchCachedData(String propertyId, Map<String, Date> cachedData) {
    return cachedData.get(propertyId);
}
```

ehCacheConfig

```html
@EnableCaching
@Configuration
public class EhCacheConfig {

    @Bean
    public EhCacheManagerFactoryBean ehCacheManagerFactory(){
        EhCacheManagerFactoryBean ehCacheBean = new EhCacheManagerFactoryBean();
        ehCacheBean.setConfigLocation(new ClassPathResource("ehcache.xml"));
        ehCacheBean.setShared(true);
        return ehCacheBean;
    }

    @Bean
    public CacheManager cacheManager() {
        SimpleCacheManager cacheManager = new SimpleCacheManager();
        List<Cache> caches = new ArrayList<Cache>();
        caches.add(new ConcurrentMapCache("responseCached"));
        cacheManager.setCaches(caches);
        return cacheManager;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you have a misunderstanding of the general concept. If you annotate a method with `@Cacheable` executions of this method are avoided, in case the data is already in the cache. In your example the cache is the `ConcurrentMapCache` not the `cachedData`. The simple example is:

```java
@Cacheable(value = "responseCached", key="#propertyId")
public Date fetchData(String propertyId) {
    // computing or I/O intensive code to produce result here
    Date d = ...
    return d;
}
```

For a unique `propertyId` the method `fetchData` is only executed once. You can omit the key definition, since it is the only parameter.

A note to your method name `fetchCachedData`: The idea of the Spring cache abstraction is, that the users of the method (ideally) don't need to know whether something is cached or not. Its best to name your method after something in the business domain, like `fetchOfferDate`.